# creating style that switches to normal style after enter

Tags: ms-word, word-2010

I'm currently formating a text where I need to use many one line headinglike styles (which do not show up in the index thus are not headings themselves).

My question is, is there any way to create a normal style (like the bold style) that can
be used so tthat enter switches back to normal style (like it is for headings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in fact this is generally the default.

When defining the style you have an option to base it on an existing style and to say what the following style is. It is at the top of the dialogue box for defining/changing style settings.

By the way, your example is perhaps not the best one. The Bold "style" isn't of course a style. One of Word's little (!) oddities. Even if it were, it would be a character style rather than a paragraph style which is what we are referring to here.

[image]

Note the entry "Style for following paragraph". That must be set to the style you want when you press enter on a paragraph styled with that style.

Comment: tzried with new sttyle (based upon heading 9 as example) base for after enter is "standard", but I still have the new style after pressing enter. is that normal or did I overlook something there?

Comment: Can you upload some screen shots somewhere and add a link. I'll embed them for you. I can show you screenshots from 2013 but not 2010 though I think it is the same.

Comment: Yeah its the same outlay (translated your screenshot to my language). 
I created a new style, then put in style type: linked, Style based on: paragraph 9, style for following paragraph: Normal  but after pressing enter it is still the new style.

Comment: Interestingly it now functions as intended after restarting the computer. tnx